# How do I make a sub directory of shared widgets in Qt?

Tags: qt, qt-creator

The issue I'm having is that I can't make stand alone headless widgets. So I have to make a master widget, make subwidgets under that. But when I do this, I can't load the subwidgets from another widget application in another sub project. I just end up getting an "unresolved external symbol" error.

I'm not entirely certain what code to show.

My tree essentially looks like this:

- main_project

  - sub_project

    - my_widget

      - my_widget.pro
      - Headers

        - my_widget.h
        - subWidget.h
      - Sources

        - my_widget.cpp
        - subWidget.cpp
        - main.cpp
      - Forms

        - my_widget.ui
        - subWidget.ui
  - different_sub_project

    - another_widget

      - another_widget.pro
      - Headers

        - another_widget.h
      - Sources

        - another_widget.cpp
        - main.cpp
      - Forms

        - another_widget.ui

SO that's what my tree looks like. I'm trying to make an instance of subwidget with another_widget. The reason is, I will have 3 or 4 (it keeps growing) widgets that all need to be able to access the same subwidgets. Nothing I have tried so far has worked. It would appear I have to duplicate every subwidget I want to use under the main widget it needs to be used in.

Answer (score 0):

Just add widget from another subproject with "Add existing files" menu  point. I.e. one your form will in 2 "pro" files. Possible you will need add path to form header to INCLUDEPATH variable of "pro" file.

Comment: This will load the widget when the app that uses it loads. Is there a method by which I could do this where the widget is only loaded when needed? I have tried making a library of widgets, but this has not worked as for some reason having a ui element precludes the use of libraries.

Comment: You can create your widget in runtime and add to another widget layout in runtime. In other words you can add widget to another widget layout in 2 ways.

Comment: ... First via QtDesigner. In that case Qt will generate C++ code that will create children widget when parent created. Second way. You will make parent widget in QtDesigner and create\add children widget_object_by your C++ code. You can choose what widget will added to parent in runtime.
All that cases can be used with solution described above.
Please let me know if that not clear for you.

Comment: I think it's clear. I'm just concerned with how that works across multiple subprojects - which is my main objective - because I would have to add the files manually to each subproject and this strikes me as inefficient.

Comment: if you will have many and many forms. Then put it all in one folder and generate pro file for that folder by "qmake -project" every time when you add new widget. Or with every compilation. After, you can include that pro file and folder to another subprojects. Also need patch INCLUDEPATH variable in that subprojects.